# Why can't I remap q

Tags: key-bindings, terminal, macro

I have many key mappings in my vimrc but for some reason no matter what I do q remains mapped to recording macros. I will post my full vimrc below, but the relevant part is that even if the last line in it is

```
nnoremap <q> <b>
```

when I press q it waits for another keypress then starts recording. I tried mapping to other things like  and  and those don't work either. If I do :map q it says no mapping found. I can remap everything else just fine, including  and .

Here is my full vimrc if that might help https://pastebin.com/6fDL2Ncb

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer was I needed

```
nnoremap q b
```

without the <>